# Confused on Cohen's Kappa - Exploring Rater Agreement Stats

Tags: r, survey, agreement-statistics, cohens-kappa, concordance

I am interested in conducting a survey where I show raters a graph then ask for their thoughts. I will do this by providing statement for which the raters will select a value on a 5 point likert scale from strongly disagree to strongly agree based on their interpretations of the graph.

My advisor thinks Cohen's Kappa would be good, but I wanted to ensure there is "good" rater agreement within each question. Also, from my understanding, if I have 3 raters and they all agree on the results except 1 rater has one different answer, my Cohen's Kappa is already 0.33 (I will have more than 3 raters, just an example).

```
library(psych)
rater1A<-c(2,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1)
rater2A<-c(2,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1)
rater3A<-c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1)
cohen.kappa(x=cbind(rater1A,rater2A,rater3A))
```

The above example rater responses gives me a Kappa value of 0.33 even though the 3 raters have the same rating for all but 1.

For each question, I don't want to say X% of raters agree because I know there is a 1/5 probability the rater chose that answer at random. For the example above, how do I tell that there is a 1/5 chance of randomly selecting that answer even though only two options were actually selected.
Any other thoughts would be greatly appreciated - new to this type of work :)